# Looping through dataframe rows in reverse

Tags: pandas, loops

I was trying to loop through dataframe rows in reverse order.

Based on row position rather than index name.

I though this code should work but its not.

```
for i, row in enumerate(df[::-1].iterrows()):  
    print (i)
```

As when I run it, it produces

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

rather than

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: try with `[i for i,r in df[::-1].iterrows()]` which gives: `[3, 2, 1, 0]` basically get rid of the `enumerate()`

Answer (score 3):

I you accept reindexing, you can also do

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.reindex().sort_index(ascending=False):  
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I thought of today to loop over a DataFrame front-ways and backwards at the same time. Of course, you don't have to do both at the same time and could simply loop backward.

You're taking the length of the index of the dataframe and then subtracting the first value returned from iterrows(), which is the index value, after adding 1 to account for the difference between index counting and length counting. You can then use that number as an index value to start from the end and loop upward.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(some_info)
length = len(df.index)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():

  opposite_index = length - (idx + 1)
  
  #Looping forward
  if row['whatever'] == whatever:
    #do something

  #Looping backward
  if df.iloc[opposite_index]['whatever'] == whatever:
    #do something
```

Note that you will need a numeric index starting from 0 for this to work. If the dataframe doesn't already have one it can be added either with `df = df.reset_index()` before your for loop, or by changing the for loop to `for idx, row in df.reset_index().iterrows():`

Answer (score -1):

The comment on how to use `iterrows()` on the question provides an answer on looping through rows of a `DataFrame` in reverse. It also introduces the idea of using a list comprehension for simplicity.

Performance and memory trouble for increasingly large datasets will be encountered. There is a more effective means of accessing the data within a `DataFrame` in reverse.

The following is contributed to help provide guidance for new Pandas users.  The gist is to place the dataframe index labels into a column which creates a new index that is ordered, preserving row position, and therefore reverse-able.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
print(pd.__version__)

# random dataframe, provides ordered rangeindex
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
# toss the ordered rangeindex and make the random 'A' the index
df.set_index(['A'], inplace=True)
# df is now a dataframe with an unordered index

def iterate(df):
    for i,r in df[::-1].iterrows():
        # process
        pass

def sort_and_apply(df):
    # apply order to the index by resetting it to a column
    # this indicates original row position by create a rangeindex.
    # (this also copies the dataframe, critically slowing down this function 
    # which is still much faster than iterate()).
    new_df = df.reset_index()

    # sort on the newly applied rangeindex and process
    new_df.sort_index(ascending=False).apply(lambda x:x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("iterate ", timeit.timeit("iterate(df)", setup="from __main__ import iterate, df", number=50))
    print("sort_and_apply ",timeit.timeit("sort_and_apply(df)", setup="from __main__ import sort_and_apply, df", number=50))
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
iterate  2.893160949
sort_and_apply  0.12744747599999995
```